# Error with supportsInterface function (ERC165)

Tags: solidity, erc-20, testing, erc165

I have this function:

```
/// @dev Checks if the type of asset-contract is same as the TokenType specified.
function _checkTokenType(Token memory _token) internal view {
    if (_token.tokenType == TokenType.ERC721) {
        try IERC165(_token.assetContract).supportsInterface(0x80ac58cd) returns (bool supported721) {
            require(supported721, "!TokenType");
        } catch {
            revert("!TokenType");
        }
    } else if (_token.tokenType == TokenType.ERC1155) {
        try IERC165(_token.assetContract).supportsInterface(0xd9b67a26) returns (bool supported1155) {
            require(supported1155, "!TokenType");
        } catch {
            revert("!TokenType");
        }
    } 
     else if (_token.tokenType == TokenType.ERC20) {
        if (_token.assetContract != CurrencyTransferLib.NATIVE_TOKEN) {
            try IERC165(_token.assetContract).supportsInterface(0x80ac58cd) returns (bool supported721) {
                require(!supported721, "!TokenType");
                try IERC165(_token.assetContract).supportsInterface(0xd9b67a26) returns (bool supported1155) {
                    require(!supported1155, "!TokenType");
                } catch Error(string memory) {}
            } catch Error(string memory) {}        
        }
    }
}
```

And I am testing it like this:

```
  describe("Loading", function () {
    describe("Co Allocated Smart Vault", function () {
      it("Owner should be able to load ERC20 to smart NFT", async function () {
        const { smartVault, owner } = await loadFixture(deploySmartVault);
        const { token } = await loadFixture(deployERC20Token)
        await smartVault.mintSmartNFT(owner.address);
        await token.approve(smartVault.address, ethers.BigNumber.from("1000000000000000"));
        await smartVault.loadTokens([[token.address,0,0,1000000000000000]], 0);
      });
    });
  });
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string
      at SmartVault._checkTokenType (contracts/extension/TokenBundle.sol:142)
      at SmartVault._createBundle (contracts/extension/TokenBundle.sol:64)
      at SmartVault._storeTokens (contracts/extension/TokenStore.sol:47)
      at SmartVault.loadTokens (contracts/vault/SmartVault.sol:233)
      at <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown> (0xb7f8bc63bbcad18155201308c8f3540b07f84f5e)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at HardhatNode._mineBlockWithPendingTxs (/home/matifalcone/Blockchain/Polygon/SmartVault/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:1815:23)
      at HardhatNode.mineBlock (/home/matifalcone/Blockchain/Polygon/SmartVault/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:504:16)
      at EthModule._sendTransactionAndReturnHash (/home/matifalcone/Blockchain/Polygon/SmartVault/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/modules/eth.ts:1522:18)
      at HardhatNetworkProvider._sendWithLogging (/home/matifalcone/Blockchain/Polygon/SmartVault/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/provider.ts:139:22)
      at HardhatNetworkProvider.request (/home/matifalcone/Blockchain/Polygon/SmartVault/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/provider.ts:116:18)
      at JsonRpcHandler._handleRequest (/home/matifalcone/Blockchain/Polygon/SmartVault/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/jsonrpc/handler.ts:188:20)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you determine which line is reverting at?

Comment: Yes, it was reverting at the `try IERC165(_token.assetContract).supportsInterface(0x80ac58cd) returns (bool supported721)` line, for ERC20. This is because ERC20 does not implement ERC165. I have modified the smart contract so it does not revert if it is not able to instantiate an IERC165 for an ERC20 token contract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to bypass this error by preventing my smart contract to revert.

`ERC20` does not implement `ERC165` by default. This means that the vast majority of tokens that interact with my contract would fail that validation.

This is the final code for the function `_checkTokenType`:

```
function _checkTokenType(Token memory _token) internal view {
    if (_token.tokenType == TokenType.ERC721) {
        try IERC165(_token.assetContract).supportsInterface(0x80ac58cd) returns (bool supported721) {
            require(supported721, "!TokenType");
        } catch {
            revert("!TokenType");
        }
    } else if (_token.tokenType == TokenType.ERC1155) {
        try IERC165(_token.assetContract).supportsInterface(0xd9b67a26) returns (bool supported1155) {
            require(supported1155, "!TokenType");
        } catch {
            revert("!TokenType");
        }
    } 
     else if (_token.tokenType == TokenType.ERC20) {
        if (_token.assetContract != CurrencyTransferLib.NATIVE_TOKEN) {
            try IERC165(_token.assetContract).supportsInterface(0x80ac58cd) returns (bool supported721) {
                require(!supported721, "!TokenType");
                try IERC165(_token.assetContract).supportsInterface(0xd9b67a26) returns (bool supported1155) {
                    require(!supported1155, "!TokenType");
                } catch (bytes memory) {}
            } catch (bytes memory) {}        
        }
    }
}
```